# Empty space at the top of the windows-phone-7 tage page

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7

Reproduced on Chrome and Firefox (no AdBlock)

Comment: I suspect this must be a *Sponsored links for this tag*. Same like [questions tagged excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel). But here the sponsored link does not load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whoops. Yup, this was a tag sponsorship that ended... Creatives stopped serving (as they should have), but the space wasn't collapsed. Thanks for letting us know - fixed now.